# Retornando apenas o último valor de uma tabela e preenchendo uma coleção via JPQL

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data, jpql

Tenho as seguintes tabelas no banco de dados:

> CLIENTE
>
> ID | NOME | CPF
>
> COMPRA
>
> ID | DESCRICAO_ | DATA | ID_CLIENTE

a tabela CLIENTE com as colunas id, nome e cpf

a tabela COMPRA com as colunas id, valor, data, id_cliente.

No código java a classe Cliente possui uma coleção de compras

Quero fazer uma consulta via Spring data JPA que retorne a paginação do seguinte DTO

```
public class ClienteDTO { 
    private Long id;
    private String nome;
    private Set<Compra> compras = new HashSet<>();


    public ClienteDTO(Long id, String nome, String descricaoItem, LocalDate data ){
        this.id = id;
        this.nome = nome;

        Compra compra = new Compra();
        compra.setDescricaoItem(descricaoItem);
        compra.setData(data);

        this.compras.add(compra);
    }       
}
```

No DTO retornado pela consulta quero que a coleção compras contenha apenas a última compra feita pelo cliente de acordo com a data.
Até agora tudo o que consegui fazer foi essa consulta:

```
@Query(
  "SELECT NEW br.meupacote.ClienteDTO(c.id, c.nome, com.descricaoItem, com.data) 
  FROM Cliente c 
  LEFT JOIN c.compras com"
)
Page<ClienteDTO> findPage(PageRequest pageRequest);
```

Nesse caso é retornado um ClienteDTO para cada compra feita pelo cliente. 
Eu gostaria de retornar apenas um ClienteDTO por cliente contendo apenas sua última compra.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boa tarde!

Você poderia fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
@Query(
  "SELECT NEW br.meupacote.ClienteDTO(c.id, c.nome, com.descricaoItem, com.data) 
  FROM Cliente c 
  LEFT JOIN c.compras com
  WHERE com.data = (SELECT max(compra.data) FROM Compra compra WHERE compra.id_cliente = com.id_cliente)"
)
Page<ClienteDTO> findPage(PageRequest pageRequest);
```

**Explicação:**

Apenas adicionei uma cláusula que verifica se a compra possui como data a maior data de compra para determinado cliente.

Com isso a consulta retornará somente as informações de um cliente e sua última compra.

Comment: Muito bom. Era exatamente isso que eu estava buscando. 
Obrigado.